# Linux version sparkylinux

Tags: linux

Hola En una laptop instalé desde usb sparky linux y me funciona. Estoy en otra laptop pero no instalé sparky lo utilizo desde el pendrive.

Al querer ejecutar el

> *sudo ./xmrig*

me aparece 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

En la otra laptop funcionó.
La diferencia es que instale sparkylinux y en esta lo ejecuto desde usb...